# frontend & backend development of an application containing "image processing" and "user authentication" steps

Tags: authentication, image-processing, backend, mobile-application

I am planning to build a mobile application (android and iOS), but I am confused. my idea is simple:
user takes a photo using her/his mobile phone, the photo is sent to the server, server checks if the user has registered or not (user authentication), if he/she is a registered user, his/her photo would be processed (some image processing steps) and finally the processed image would be sent back to user's mobile.

I know I should have a frontend and a backend. what programming languages should I use? I have googled a lot but yet no success. someone suggested using Laravel for user authentication but I am not sure if Laravel could handle the image processing steps as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being unaware of your experience and preference of programming language, I recommend to start with the [Django framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/), which is based on Python and receives a growing interest after its release in 2005. Probably the most famous project using Django is [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com), whose core functionality is close to what you are after.

A good example project for you to start with can be found here:

https://github.com/axelpale/minimal-django-file-upload-example